# QVTKOpenGLWidget and vtkGenericOpenGlRenderWindow with QTDesigner

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, vtk, viewer

I'm trying to use `QVTKOpenGLWidget` in QTDesigner with `vtkGenericOpenGlRenderWindow` but I obtain a black window. When I use `PCLVizualizer` of PointCloud Library (PCL) with `vtkGenericOpenGlRenderWindow`, everything works fine. I'm trying to create a custom viewer the same way as PCL.

```
QMainPanel::QMainPanel( HWND hWnd ) :
    QWinWidget( hWnd ),
    ui(new Ui::QMainPanel)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    rendererTest = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    rendererTest->GradientBackgroundOn();
    rendererTest->SetBackground(0.27,0.27,0.27);
    rendererTest->SetBackground2(0.44,0.44,0.44);
    windowTest = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow>::New();
    windowTest->AddRenderer(rendererTest);
    interactorTest = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    interactorTest->SetRenderWindow( windowTest );
    ui->openGLWidget->SetRenderWindow( windowTest ); //  QVTKOpenGLWidget *openGLWidget;
}
```

Thank you

**Edit : 
Remove "Interactor" solved my problem.**

Comment: Up :) My problem is not solved :(

Comment: You should avoid editing your question to mark it as solved. Instead, write a complete answer to your original question, explaining how you solved your issue. Then, you can accept your own answer. This is perfectly valid regarding Stack Overflow rules, and makes easy for future readers to understand the problem and the solution

Answer (score 4):

You will need to get the master version of PCL form https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl. This will give a PCLVisualizer with more constructors. So, you can use a custom widget like this:

**VideoQVTKOpenGLWidget.h**

```
    #ifndef VIDEOQVKTOPENGLWIDGET_H
    #define VIDEOQVKTOPENGLWIDGET_H

    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QVTKOpenGLWidget.h>
    #include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
    using namespace pcl::visualization;

    class VideoQVTKOpenGLWidget : public QVTKOpenGLWidget
    {
      public:
        explicit VideoQVTKOpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
        void populateCloud(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud);

      private:
        boost::shared_ptr<PCLVisualizer> _viewer;
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow> _renderWindow;
    };

    #endif // VIDEOQVKTOPENGLWIDGET_H
```

**VideoQVTKOpenGLWidget.cpp**

```
    #include "VideoQVTKOpenGLWidget.h"

    #include <vtkPointPicker.h>
    #include <vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow.h>

    VideoQVTKOpenGLWidget::VideoQVTKOpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent)
      : QVTKOpenGLWidget(parent)
    {
      auto renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
      _renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow>::New();
      _renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
      _viewer.reset(new PCLVisualizer(renderer, _renderWindow, "viewer", false));
      this->SetRenderWindow(_viewer->getRenderWindow());
      this->update();
    }

    void VideoQVTKOpenGLWidget::populateCloud(pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud)
    {
      if(!_viewer->updatePointCloud(cloud, "cloud")) {
        _viewer->addPointCloud(cloud, "cloud");
      }
      _renderWindow->Render();
    }
```