# using QVTKOpenGLWidget with Qt causing project to crash

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, point-cloud-library, qvtkwidget

I have a working project on Qt using pcl and vtk....I was using QVTKWidget.

Now I need to re-build the project using QVTKOpenGLWidget as QVTKWidget is deprecated

This post suggests that the latest PCL version from master should be used 
[QVTKOpenGLWidget and vtkGenericOpenGlRenderWindow with QTDesigner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498363/qvtkopenglwidget-and-vtkgenericopenglrenderwindow-with-qtdesigner))

I did that and changed the necessary files but when compiling the project always crashes when I link pclVisuiliser with QVTKOpenGLWidget.

```
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(QVTKOpenGLWidget::defaultFormat());

QApplication app(argc, argv);

QVTKOpenGLWidget *widget = new QVTKOpenGLWidget();

vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;
vtkNew<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow> renderWindow;
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer.Get());

pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr pclViewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer(renderer.Get(), renderWindow.Get(), "viewer", false));
widget->SetRenderWindow(pclViewer->getRenderWindow());

widget->show();
```

When these two lines are commented out the project doesn't crash :

```
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr pclViewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer(renderer.Get(), renderWindow.Get(), "viewer", false));
widget->SetRenderWindow(pclViewer->getRenderWindow());
```

I'm using Qt 5.9.5 and latest version from master on github for PCl and VTK.

Is there anything missing ?

Comment: Is this code part of the main() function of your application?

Comment: For your information, a new QVTKOpenGLWidget is coming. https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/merge_requests/3745

Comment: One year later and still waiting for this merge.  The old one that is deprecated and the new one that crashes... that's maddening.